# How to create Oracle DB connection via Java and Tomcat?

Tags: java, database, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to use Oracle DB via Java and Tomcat. 
The problem is that I can not configurate correct connection via connection pool and declaration in "server.xml" file. 
So, when I use this code in a Java class:

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"); 
Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:my","system","****"); 
String sql = "SELECT * FROM TestTable2"; 
PreparedStatement pStatement =con.prepareStatement(sql); 
ResultSet rs = pStatement.executeQuery(sql);
```

Everything works fine. 
But when I use this code in a Java class:

```
Context initContext = new 
InitialContext(); 
Context envContext = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env"); 
DataSource datasource = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/LocalMyDataBaseOracle"); 
Connection sqlCon = datasource.getConnection(); 

String sql = "SELECT * FROM TestTable2"; 
PreparedStatement pStatement =sqlCon.prepareStatement(sql); 

ResultSet rs = pStatement.executeQuery(sql);
```

This code in

```
<ResourceLink type="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" 
name="jdbc/LocalMyDataBaseOracle" 
global="jdbc/MyDataBaseOracle" 
/>
```

and this code in

```
<Resource driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" 
factory="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSourceFactory" 
name="jdbc/MyDataBaseOracle" 
username="system" 
password="****" 
type="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" 
url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:my" 

autoReconnectForConnectionPools="true" 
autoReconnectForPools="true" 
testOnBorrow="true" 
testWhileIdle="true" 
validationQuery="select 1 from dual" 
validationInterval="34" 
/>
```

I get an exception "java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied" in line    `Connection sqlCon = datasource.getConnection();`

The username and the password are the same in first and second codes. please advise what is going wrong ?

Comment: 1) Password has only english letters and numeral.
2) I use SYSTEM just for a moment while I can not establish connection, then I will change it.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I'm thinking about is that you're having some national characters in password and due to different encoding from Java file and config xml it goes different. Unless it is just typo.

Btw. Why do you log in as system user which is rather for internal stuff?